# How to set Title of CMD to current working Directory in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

How does one set the title of the of the Command Prompt (CMD) in Windows XP to the current working directory dynamically ? I can use

```
title %CD%
```

however, this is a temporary fix and the title remains fixed when I change directory using the CD command.

Comment: Well, what happens when you use `pushd` with one of the macros?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Got it to work thanks to gravvity's doskey macro. He has used && to combine the cd and title commands which works perfectly. I even made this macro load every time I use cmd by tweaking the registry.

1) I created a bat file called **cmd_title.bat** and it contents are

```
@echo off
title %cd%
```

2) I placed this file in the C: drive (C:\cmd_title.bat)

3) Create another batch file called **cmd.bat** in the C: drive with the following contents

```
doskey cd = cd /d $* ^&^& "C:\cmd_title.bat"
title %cd%
```

(the /d flag is for using cd to switch to another drive).

4) Then we open regedit and go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor**. Here there is a key called **AutoRun**. We modify the value of this key and set it to the location of the **cmd.bat** file in quotes (eg: "C:\cmd.bat").

Now cd works as we want every time we open cmd.

Basically && is used for command chaining in Windows

Comment: Cool, I got your solution to work. But I lost my "hit tab key, auto-match" functionality.

Comment: You might have disturbed the CompletionChar/PathCompletionChar values in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor key in the registry. To set use the tab key for auto-completion you need to set the CompletionChar and PathCompletionChar values to 0x9 (hex)

Comment: +1 it is a working solution, but with minor correction: AutoRun is not a key, but *value* of type of string.

Comment: When we shift+right click on a folder in windows explorer, we have an option for opening command prompt on that folder. This solution doesn't work in that case. Does anyone know a quick fix to this?

Comment: @bits There is a solution to make it work with shift+right click here: https://superuser.com/questions/414155/cmd-exe-customizing-the-open-command-prompt-here-shell-extension

Comment: If you want it to run it on particular command prompt windows, create a new shortcut and append  "/k c:\cmd.bat" to the shortcut's target

Comment: Nice solution! You could also do it without the cmd_title.bat if you type the macro like this instead: `doskey cd=@echo off$Tcd /d $*$T@title ^%cd^%$Techo on`

Comment: I find `@echo off` is not necessary if you just add `@` in front of the commands you don't want echoed.  I also found this command more useful to set the title to just the current directory name instead of the full path `@for %%* in (.) do @title %%~nx*`

Comment: This solution works, but it means that you cannot add your own `/d` flag when you call `cd`. For instance:"H:\>cd /d V:\" gives you the message "The syntax of the command is incorrect." I actually think that `cd` should always work like `cd /d`, and this will save me some typing, so I consider it an improvement. However, it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Also note that with this system, if you simply type a drive letter (e.g., "V:\") to go to a directory, the title won't get updated. You need to use "cd" (e.g., "cd V:\").

Answer (score 6):

I think that pushd and popd are much more useful than cd, and would see a lot more use if they were quicker to type. I have resolved the issues of cd vs. pushd/popd and console window directory title with the following script, which I call d.bat, which is in my path.

```
@ echo off
rem d.bat replaces CD, PUSHD, and POPD with one command that also changes the title
rem of the console window to tell the current directory. Invoked with no arg, the
rem title is updated. Use this after changing the directory by some other means.
rem The argument / invokes popd. Any other argument invokes pushd with that arg.

if not _%1 == _ ( 
    if _%1 == _/ (
        popd
    ) else (
        pushd %*
    )
)
title %CD%
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Command Prompt's title by using the `title` command.

You may create a batch file (say mycd.bat) containing:

```
title "%1"
cd  "%1"
```

and use it instead of "cd" :

```
mycd "newdir"
```

You can also put the .bat file in system32 if you wish it to always be available.

Comment: Using macros would be a better option: `doskey cd=cd $* ^&^& title $*`

Comment: @grawity: Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not with the Windows shell.

---

It *might* be possible to add "set Xterm title" escape sequences to `%PROMPT%`, but you would need a different terminal emulator (perhaps PuTTYcyg or something from SfU), as Windows Console does not support escape sequences.

Alternatively, find another shell which can use the Windows console functions to set titles.

---

These are often confused in Windows contexts, so...

*shell* reads and interprets input; `cmd.exe`, `command.com`, `/bin/sh`

*terminal*, *terminal emulator*, *console* displays text-based programs (including the shell) on your screen; `Windows Console`, `xterm`, `PuTTYcyg`

Comment: actually, cmd.exe is a terminal. explorer is a shell.

Comment: @Idigas: `explorer` is a GUI shell, `cmd.exe` is a text-based one. (Think about it: `cmd.exe` is the exact equivalent of `/bin/sh` in Unix, and `/bin/sh` is always called "the shell". Similarly, the Windows Console is equivalent to a "terminal emulator" in X11.)

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming \tools is in the path, and it's where you keep your batch files:

```
copy con: \tools\titlecmd.txt

title ^Z

copy con: \tools\cdtitle.bat

cd>\tools\cd.txt

copy \tools\titlecmd.txt+\tools\cd.txt cdtitletmp.bat

call cdtitletmp

^Z
```

You now have a `cdtitle.bat` that you can call from another batch file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file: cd.bat and put the following in there:

```
cd %*  
title %CD%
```

Then issue this command:

```
doskey cd=...\cd.bat $*
```

Replace "..." with the path to cd.bat. Try it out and see that it works.

To make that permanent-ish, create dosrc.cmd, put that doskey command in there, and then create a cmd shortcut, right click on it and select properties.

Modify Target to be:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K ...\dosrc.cmd
```

Again, replace "..." with the path to dosrc.cmd

Then double click on the shortcut, you should have the cd functionality.