# Title of cmd windows (in task bar)

Tags: windows, command-line, taskbar, console

I often find myself end up with several cmd windows which I need to be open for several days at a time.

When I hover on the clumped cmd icon in task bar (in windows 7), it shows me something like this (see screenshot below):

[image: How it looks on my task bar]

All those CMDs have different current directory. I always have to do a hit-and-trial to restore every window to find the one where I want to work. If after restoring, its not the intended one, then I minimize it and restore next. Rinse and repeat. Its quite counter-productive.

What I would prefer is that instead of useless information like "Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", it should show the current duirectory that cmd is in.

Is there a way do achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered wrapping CMD in Console2, which will give you tabs in a single window?  That would make running so many instances much easier.  You could do the same with TCC/LE, which I find much better than CMD.

Comment: You might want to check out this solution provided in here.
It's pretty much straightforward and suits your needs i think.
http://superuser.com/a/143784/155564

Comment: Check out this question also: http://superuser.com/q/459154/139371 The idea is to use ANSI escape sequences in prompt, but you need to use ANSI "processor" - [ConEmu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) or [AnsiCon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon).

Answer (score 4):

Within the command window, use the [TITLE](http://ss64.com/nt/title.html) command.

```
Syntax
  TITLE [string]

Key
  string  The title for the command prompt window, up to 243 characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the Command Prompt change its title whenever the working directory changes.

For example, to achieve this when using `cd` to change directories, define the following macro

```
doskey cd=cd C:\cd.bat $*
```

and create a batch file (`C:\cd.bat`) containing the following:

```
@echo off

cd %*

title %cd%
```

If you write similar files for `pushd` and `popd` (just replace `cd`), you can create a batch file (e.g., `C:\macros.bat`) that sets the title to the current location and defines macros for `cd`, `pushd`, `popd` and the `X:` command:

```
@echo off

title %cd%

doskey cd=C:\cd.bat $*
doskey popd=C:\popd.bat $*
doskey pushd=C:\pushd.bat $* 

for %%b in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V V X Y Z) do @doskey %%b:=C:\cd.bat /D %%b:
```

To get a Command Prompt with these macros, either invoke it like this:

```
cmd /K C:\macros.bat
```

or create a **String** value with **Name** *AutoRun* and **Data** *C:\macros.bat* in the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```